# How to multiply input images with mask in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to multiply every input image with a mask of the same size as the input image. How would I do that in tensorflow?

My image reading function looks like this so far:

```
img_contents = tf.read_file(input_queue[0])
label_contents = tf.read_file(input_queue[1])
img = tf.image.decode_png(img_contents, channels=3) 
label = tf.image.decode_png(label_contents, channels=1)

# Now I want to do something like this?
mask = tf.constant(1.0, dtype=tf.float32, shape=img.shape)
img_masked = tf.multiply(img,mask)
```

Is that possible?
Not sure if img is already a tensor object and I can use that function here. I'm new to tensorflow...

Comment: You can simply do
`mask = tf.constant(1.0, dtype=tf.float32, shape=img.get_shape())`
`img_masked = img * mask`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that works well for me. I'm using jupyter notebook to run the code.

```py
%matplotlib inline
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib.image import imread 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Loading test image from the local filesystem 
x = tf.Variable(imread("test_img.jpg"),dtype='float32')
x_mask = tf.Variable(imread("test_mask.jpg"),dtype='float32')
img_mult = tf.multiply(x,x_mask)

plt.imshow(imread("test_img.jpg"))
plt.show()
plt.imshow(imread("test_mask.jpg"))
plt.show()

sess = tf.Session() 
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
res = sess.run(img_mult)

plt.imshow(res)
plt.show()
```

Also, Here is a good YouTube tutorial covering image manipulation with TF: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvHgESVuS6Q&t=447s